# Building search functionality in a web-app

Tags: angularjs, search, web, web-applications

I am currently developing a help section (web-app) using angular.js to represent something pretty close to this https://help.instagram.com/

I have several pages which discuss's several aspects of the product at hand. Now, i am stuck with trying to implement a in app search feature so that users can simply search for something that they may be looking for.

Some heads up with where i could start and what i should be doing would be really helpful! Thanks a ton guys :)

Comment: This is mostly backend stuff. So have your  backend guys do this:)

Comment: Could set up a route that has query term as route param. Then url encode the user search term and load that path using `$location.path()` or `$state` methods if using angular-ui router. Use route param to make `$http` request